# Two text area side by side with min width but when text longer collapse the left side

Tags: html, css

I have this problem on responsive I have this two text area

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-md-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.btn-group {
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form__group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.form__input {
    height: 40px;
}
.horizontal-scroll {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    }
.horizontal-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 7px; 
      height: 4px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      border-radius: 4px;
      z-index: 9999;
    }

 .horizontal-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      z-index: 9999;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 4px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
      }
    }
}
.disabled-custom {
    resize: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: #e4ebf8;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.form__input {
    border: 1px solid #ccd4e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
}
.form__label {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #324161;
    display: table-header-group;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="form__group" style="    margin-right: 24px;"> 

                          <textarea wrap="off" class="form__input disabled-custom horizontal-scroll" style="min-width: 600px;" readonly>https://app.zeplin.io/project/5bb1fdc046eb4d20e8405978/screen/5c18f75217aa3f24677c39a8</textarea>

                          <label class="form__label">aijsdoaisjdoiajsoidjais</label>
                        </div>
                    
                                <div class="form__group">
                          <textarea wrap="off" class="form__input disabled-custom horizontal-scroll" style="min-width: 120px;" readonly>30 Points</textarea>
                          <label for="test_passing_sc" class="form__label">Test Passing Scoreasdasjdajsn</label>
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The left text area with label included it has width of 600px min and the right 120px I managed when text longer for the left text area I put a horizontal scroll but for the right side i need when the text its longer to be able to auto width on the left side and the left text area to decrease width.. Can someone help me with this..?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!Doctype html>
<style>
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    .col-md-12 {
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .btn-group {
        display: inline-flex;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .form__group {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .form__input {
        height: 40px;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 7px;
        height: 4px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        border-radius: 4px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        z-index: 9999;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 2px;
        width: 4px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }

    .disabled-custom {
        resize: none;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background: #e4ebf8;
        border: none;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .form__input {
        border: 1px solid #ccd4e3;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        padding-top: 1.1rem;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
    }

    .form__label {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #324161;
        display: table-header-group;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="form__group" style="margin-right: 24px;">
                    <textarea wrap="off" class="form__input disabled-custom horizontal-scroll" style="min-width: 120px;" readonly>https://app.zeplin.io/project/5bb1fdc046eb4d20e8405978/screen/5c18f75217aa3f24677c39a8</textarea>
                    <label class="form__label">Input 1</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="form__group" style="margin-right: 24px;">
                    <textarea wrap="off" class="form__input disabled-custom horizontal-scroll" style="min-width: 120px;" readonly>30 Points</textarea>
                    <label for="test_passing_sc" class="form__label">Input 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This would work for  or you can use bootstrap, it would save you a whole lot of stress